# Power BI How to filter report by value in column

Tags: filtering, powerbi

I just want to ask if its possible to filter value base on the value in a column.

I want them to show it categorized by the `Tier` Column, but what happening is that it shows all the data the same as each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each of those four bar charts, you can set a visual level filter corresponding with the tier you want to show.

[image: Visual level filters]

Comment: its there a chance i can only filter the top 10 on the list?

Comment: Yes, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768951/top-n-customer-names-as-a-slicer-in-power-bi

Comment: Thank you Alex. it really works. one more thing to make this look perfect. i just need to arrange it from highest to lowest.